# VQ-VAE - Commitment Loss

Tags: autoencoders, generative-models

Why the commitment loss is necessary in the VQ-VAE objective function?
I understand that it's serving the role of keeping the encoder outputs(continuous latent representations) close to the codebook.
What I don't understand is why the encoder outputs will tend to blow up/grow to infinity without this commitment term?
we know that in a normal auto-encoder it doesn't happen, we only minimize the reconstruction loss and the latent representations don't grow up unboundedly.